# NaN result when converting Bytes To Megabytes

Tags: vb.net

how can I fix my method of converting Bytes To Megabytes not to get as a Result NaN.
This is my method:

```
   Public Function BytesToMegabytes(bytes As Long) As String
        Dim dblAns As Double = (bytes / 1024) / 1024

        If dblAns = 0 Then
            Return "0"
        End If

        Dim significantFigures = 4
        Dim magnitude = Math.Floor(Math.Log10(dblAns)) 'In this Line I get the NaN
        Dim v As Double = 10 ^ (magnitude - significantFigures + 1)
        dblAns = Math.Floor(dblAns / v) * v

        Dim ci = New CultureInfo("")
        ci.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator = ","
        ci.NumberFormat.NumberGroupSeparator = "'"

        Return dblAns.ToString("#,##0.###", ci)

    End Function
```

With `Dim usedInklData = BytesToMegabytes(-3271356861)`  I get the correct result.
and with `Dim usedInklData = BytesToMegabytes(-776150324)`  I get the NaN value.

Please suggest how I could correct this.

Thanks to everyone for their help.

Comment: What happens when you debug this method? Which variables do/do not match your expectations at each stage? [How to Debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: Math.Log10() is [not defined](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.math.log10?view=net-5.0) for negative arguments.  So you can't get the 'correct result' for -3271356861 either.  Consider whether a negative number of bytes is sensible, consider using Math.Abs(dlbAns)

Comment: @HansPassant  In this Line I get the NaN value :
  Dim magnitude = Math.Floor(Math.Log10(dblAns)) but using Math.Abs() I get the same value

Comment: ah, just noticed that you have signed values. What does, for example a `-10MB` value mean to you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about you remember if your input is negative and flip the result if it is, after doing the calculation in positive numbers:

```
Public Function BytesToMegabytes(bytes As Long) As String
    Dim isNeg = bytes < 0
    If isNeg Then bytes *= -1

    Dim dblAns As Double = (bytes / 1024) / 1024

    If dblAns = 0 Then
        Return "0"
    End If

    Dim significantFigures = 4
    Dim magnitude = Math.Floor(Math.Log10(dblAns)) 'In this Line I get the NaN
    Dim v As Double = 10 ^ (magnitude - significantFigures + 1)
    dblAns = Math.Floor(dblAns / v) * v

    Dim ci = New CultureInfo("")
    ci.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator = ","
    ci.NumberFormat.NumberGroupSeparator = "'"

    If isNeg Then dblAns *= -1

    Return dblAns.ToString("#,##0.###", ci)

End Function
```